# Arc length of the curve $y=x^p$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ is an increasing function of $p$ for $p\ge1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Show that the arc length of the curve $y=x^p$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ is an increasing function of $p$ for $p\ge1$

As far as I know, this cannot be done using the arc length formula... Would a geometric argument work?

Comment: Maybe you could use the fact that  a convex curve contained inside another curve is shorter.

Comment: @orangeskid this doesn't hold water.

Comment: Have you checked it numerically?

Comment: @Vim: Check out the answer - look at the picture with an open mind.

Answer (score 1):

@orangeskid has hinted in a comment that one might use the fact that a convex arc inside another convex arc is shorter. Here is a proof of this fact, which then settles the problem.

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth convex arc of total turning angle $<\pi$, connecting the points $p$ and $q$ in the plane. From $p$ and $q$ draw tangent rays extending out to infinity. In this way the plane is divided into a concave and a convex part. I claim that the shortest curve connecting $p$ and $q$ and lying completely in the concave part is $\gamma$.

*Proof.* From each point of $\gamma$ draw an outward normal to infinity. Any admissible curve $\sigma$ connecting $p$ and $q$ has to intersect all these normals, and from the convexity of $\gamma$ it follows that the length of $\sigma$ between "infinitesimally close" normals is greater than the length of $\gamma$ between these normals.

Comment: The deformed curve $\gamma_1 = \gamma - \alpha \cdot n$ so $\frac{d \gamma_1}{d s} = (1 + \alpha k) t - \alpha' n$, longer than $t$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The red curve is longer than the green curve.

[image]

$\bf{Added:}$ One shows that a closed  curve is longer than any closed convex curve contained inside.  One way is to approximate the curves with polygons. In finitely many steps one can cut away polygonal pieces from the outside domain to reveal the inner convex one. At each step the perimeter decreases. Another way is to note that the the length of a closed curve is larger or equal to $\pi \cdot $  [mean width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_width) ( think of a circle), with equality for closed curves. The width in any direction is larger for the outside curve.

This property of convex curves was one taught in some high schools, check for instance some [pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNF80.png) from a high school textbook.