# integral inequality increasing continuous function.

Tags: calculus, contest-math

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ and $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ be two non-decreasing continuous functions such that for all $x\in [a,b]$ we have $\int\limits_{a}^x \sqrt{f(t)}dt\leq \int\limits_{a}^x \sqrt{g(t)}dt$ with equality when $x=b$.

Prove that $\int\limits_{a}^b \sqrt{f(t)+1}dt\geq \int\limits_a^b \sqrt{g(t)+1}dt$

I think that we should somehow use the concavity of the square root function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $u(x)=\int_{a}^{x}\sqrt{f(t)}dt$ and $v(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{g(t)}dt$

Then $\int_{a}^{x}\sqrt{f(t)+1}dt=\int_{a}^{x}\sqrt{(u'(t))^2+1}dt$ is the arc length of the graph of $u(t)$ between $a$ and $x$.

The given inequality tells us that the graph of $v$ is never below the graph of $u$. The two graphs meet at $x=a$ and at $x=b$.

But since $f,g$ are non-negative (and therefore $\sqrt{f},\sqrt{g}$ are non-negative), we have that the derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are always positive.

$f,g$ might not be differentiable, but the increment of the derivative of $u$ and $v$ can still be computed. For $s>0$

$$u'(t+s)-u'(t)=\sqrt{f(t+s)}-\sqrt{f(t)}=\frac{f(t+s)-f(t)}{\sqrt{f(t+s)}+\sqrt{f(t)}}\geq0$$

Therefore $u,v$ are convex, one below the other and meet at the two end-points. Therefore the one below has a longer arc than the one above.

---

The last step is still meaty, but since it is not too hard, well-known, and a bit tedious to explain, I left it out.

An argument, not completely precise, has been given for example in an [answer to this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1140418/464638).

Comment: can you provide a proof or some sources on the result used to conclude ( about one convex function dominating the other=

Comment: @TacNayn Added a link to one.